# API calls fail with Rate limit exceeded in OneLogin

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, onelogin, rate-limiting

I am trying to make a API call to Onelogin (which is a third-party identity platform), it fails with "Rate limit exceeded", after 5000 request. How can I increase the request or reset the counter?

Answer (score 0):

There is an account level rate limit of 5,000 calls per hour regardless of how many access tokens you have. If an access token surpasses this limit, API calls will return an error. After the hour has passed, the count will be reset to a full 5,000 available calls.

https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/oauth20-tokens/get-rate-limit

Comment: Yes. I read this link, I don't understand what it means by Account level rate limit? Second, what is there anyway I can make more than 5000 request?

Comment: rate limits are usually implemented to restrict access to the service and prevent DDOS in some cases. regarding the second point, the only way to be able to perform more than 5000 requests per hour is to ask OneLogin to increase the limit for your account (of course if they offer this)

Answer (score 0):

Free/Developer accounts are limited to 5000 API calls per hour.

If you're a paying customer, you can contact OneLogin support to get your rate limit increased.